# How to change button color on button click in C#?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am creating an online test application, in which I am generating approximately 100 buttons at run time on form load. Here is the piece of code:w

```
private void addQuestion_Reviewbutton()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= clsGlobalVars.gnTotalQuestion; i++)
            {
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Location = new Point(160, 30 * i + 10);
                button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClickOneEvent);                
                button.Tag = i;                
                button.Name = "Question" + i;
                button.Text = i.ToString();
                button.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.button));
                button.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;//.Zoom;
                button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(47, 41);
                button.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                button.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 12);
                button.ForeColor = Color.White;
                button.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
                
            }
        }
```

and on this button click, I am changing the background-color.

```
void ButtonClickOneEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            //button.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            button.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.button_Orange));
            lblQuestionNo.Text = ((int)button.Tag).ToString()+".";
            btnNext.Focus();
            
        }
```

I have a button on the form Named "Next". Now my problem is that if I am currently in question "1." and I press the button next I want to change the background image of the button whose text is "2".

Comment: What technology are you creating this in? Is this webforms?

Comment: Yes in Webforms.

Comment: So if current `Button` has `Tag == 1` you want to find the `Button` with `Tag == 2`? Why not just loop over these buttons? Or query with a help of Linq? `var nextButton = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(btn => btn.Tag == currentButton.Tag + 1);`

Comment: You could pass the next Button Tag as an [CommandArgument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument?view=netframework-4.8) to save you the trouble of having to convert back to `int` to incrememt.

Comment: **You should not be using WebForms for new projects in 2021**. It's been obsolete for 13 years already. _Yikes_.

Comment: "I need your valuable guidance to solve this problem." - my guidance is for you to _stop immediately_ and start-over in ASP.NET Core, or at least ASP.NET MVC (for .NET Framework), otherwise you'll have sunk more and more time into a web-framework that _does not work well with modern web-browsers_. For example, every "event" handled on the server requires a form `POST`, which breaks your user's browsers' Back button, which is a really crappy UX (so if the user submits answers for a dozen questions (_each_ requiring their own `POST`) and then accidentally navigate back they've lost everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo check this !

tldr; the guidance are

1. Is the click event go to ButtonClickOneEvent ?
2. How to call other button
3. ...
4. profit?

   ```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       addQuestion_Reviewbutton();
    }

     void ButtonClickOneEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;

        var currentbtn_id = button.ID; 
        int nextid =  Convert.ToInt32( currentbtn_id.Substring("Question".Length)) + 1;
       var nextBtn = flowLayoutPanel1.FindControl("Question"+ nextid.ToString() );
        (nextBtn as Button).BackColor = Color.Red;

    }
   ```

[image]